# Unable to wrap text properly while underlining a variable in fpdf

Tags: php, html, fpdf

I am having trouble getting my page to line up right.  I followed some other ideas about using the xy values to place my words, but the third multicell is getting pushed to the middle of the page and not wrapping back to the left margin.  I have no idea how long the variable length is each time, so I can't just set it.

```
$x=$pdf->GetX();
$y=$pdf->GetY();

$pdf->MultiCell(0,7,'I, ');
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','U',14);
$pdf->SetXY($x+4,$y);
$i = strlen($Sellers);

$pdf->MultiCell(0,7,$Sellers);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',14);
$pdf->SetXY($x+$i,$y);

$pdf->MultiCell(0,7,', the undersigned sellers of said property do hereby authorize Person to conduct business on behalf of sell: ');
```

Any ideas.  I need it to basically say I, underlined Seller names, Do authorize blah blah blah.

Thank you

Comment: Could you setup the exact example, fpdf isn't something that is running out of the box with php.

Comment: That is the exact example, with just some wording changed in the actual phrase.